# The same PDF file is shown differently in iPad and Mac

Tags: pdf, ipad, xmarks

I bought a PDF book from O'Reilly, and copied the file to iPad to read.

And it I see some marks as below. I tested with a couple of PDF apps and all of my apps show the marks.

[image]

And this is the screen capture to open with Preview.app in Mac which doesn't have the mark.

- Why is this? Does the Preview.app or Acrobat cuts out the marks whereas the iPad apps don't (or can't)?
- Is that a bug in iPad app?
- Is there a PDF tool to remove those marks?
- Is there an iPad app that doesn't show the marks?

[image]

### ADDED

I tested with some of my iPad pdf apps.

- iBook - OK
- PDFReader - shows the marks
- iAnnotate - shows the marks
- Note Taker HD - shows the marks

I think some (or most) of the iPad pdf readers doesn't process the marks correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this?

Those marks are called Printer marks or Crop marks. They are used for professional document production such as printing books.

> Does the Preview.app or Acrobat cuts out the marks whereas the iPad
>   apps don't (or can't)?

It seems as if Preview.app and Acrobat intelligently ignore printer marks, whereas other apps do not.

> Is that a bug in iPad app?

I do not think it is a bug.

> Is there a PDF tool to remove those marks?

There is a question about this [on stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212256/removing-printer-marks-from-a-pdf-file), but in short, cropping the document will get rid of the marks.

> Is there an iPad app that doesn't show the marks?

I don't know of any than can automatically hide crop marks, but advanced pdf reading apps for iPad such as [Goodreader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html) allow you to crop the pdf on the fly.